# create a cookie with javascript in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, cookies, greasemonkey

i'm trying to create a cookie with greasemonkey in order to stop a window from popping up (after the windows pops up a cookie is created the the window won't popup to many times...
this is the code

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ?
        "" :
        ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}

var cookie_names = [
    'showDrushimPopUnderUserClick',
    'showDrushimPopUnder308'
];

for (var i in cookie_names) {
    setCookie(cookie_names[i], 1, 0);
}
```

but no cookie is been created....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set a cookie that has an `expires` value equal to, or older than, the current system clock, it actually ***deletes*** the named cookie instead (Unless the `path` or `domain` are different, or it is a "secure" cookie -- none of which apply here).

This:

```
setCookie(cookie_names[i], 1, 0);
```

Causes that function to set a cookie with an instant expiration value, effectively deleting any cookie with that name.

To actually set a new cookie, use:

```
setCookie(cookie_names[i], 1, null);
```

which will cause your code to set a session cookie -- which is probably what you want.

Or use:

```
setCookie(cookie_names[i], 1, 1);
```

To set a cookie that expires in a day.

Comment: tried both null and 1 but didn't solve. the cookie is not been created as i see in firefox

Comment: It works perfectly, I just double checked.  If it's not working for you, then either there is something else going on with your script, or how you are checking for cookies.  Link to your complete script; use http://pastebin.com/, if necessary. ... How are you checking for cookies?

Comment: this is all the script...
im checking with fire bug.
i also tried to create a cookie with a different name and it's not been created

Comment: If that's "all the script", then that is a problem, that is **not a valid script.**  It's a valid code snippet only.  Open the Greasemonkey script manager, find your script, right-click on it and select ***Edit***.  The file should open in whatever text editor you configured Greasemonkey to open.  Paste the contents of that file at pastebin and link to it.

Comment: ofcourse there is more heading and so look here for the full script http://pastebin.com/jP5W2Vu8

Comment: That script works fine, for me, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/0VxfC.gif. However, it (re)set the cookies 11 times, because that page uses a crapton of iframes. (Not necessarily a problem, but inefficient.)   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4190594/331508) for stopping the script from firing repeatedly for iframes.

Comment: Uninstall all scripts that work on that page.  Then restart Firefox and reinstall just the cookie script and retest.  Note you may need to refresh the page an extra time to see the cookies with Firebug.