# How do I stop the function in TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have a script in TamperMonkey that I want to run once then stop. It should prompt the user then fill in boxes then stop. But it keeps asking...

```
function logIn() {
    s = prompt('Enter your username')
    document.getElementById("Header_Login_tbUsername").value = s;

    s2 = prompt('Enter your password')
    document.getElementById("Header_Login_tbPassword").value = s2;
    document.getElementById('Header_Login_btLogin').click();

    a = prompt('Paste the link')
    window.location.replace(a);
}

logIn();
```

Comment: Create a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

Comment: A [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452626/create-a-cookie-with-javascript-in-greasemonkey) that deals with GreaseMonkey, but should be portable. ***Note:** This question seems like the perfect solution for you.*

Comment: You're going to have to provide details. What are the URL's that the script runs on?  What are the URL's that you redirect (`location.replace(a)`) to? Edit the question to provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the latter cookie functions to your script to create, check, and delete cookies.

Each time your script runs, check for the cookies existence:

```
function logIn() {
    var cookieValue = 'myLogin';
    var exists = readCookie(cookieValue);

    // If the cookie is not set, prompt to enter login and create cookie.
    if (!exists) {
        createCookie(cookieValue, '', 1); // Store for 1 day.
        promptLogin();
    }
}

function promptLogin() {
    s = prompt('Enter your username');
    document.getElementById("Header_Login_tbUsername").value = s;

    s2 = prompt('Enter your password');
    document.getElementById("Header_Login_tbPassword").value = s2;
    document.getElementById('Header_Login_btLogin').click();

    a = prompt('Paste the link');
    window.location.replace(a);
}

logIn();
```

Check [QuirksMode: Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for a more in-depth discussion on the code below.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 86400000);
        expires = "; expires =" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: You may need to verify that the login was successful before creating the cookie, or it will not ask you again. That is, until you delete the cookie.