# How to add frames to an existing frameset using userscript?

Tags: javascript, frames, userscripts, frameset

The target page has a simple HTML setup:

```
<html>
<body>
    <frameset id="mainset" rows="50%,50%">
    ...
    </frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

and I'd like to add frames using JavaScript.

---

This doesn't work:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[0];
var child = document.createElement("frame");
child.src = "about:blank";
child.style = "background-color: red;";

parent.appendChild(child);
```

This does work, but it creates an iframe:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var child = document.createElement("iframe");
child.src = "about:blank";
child.style = "background-color: red;";

parent.appendChild(child);
```

Is there a way to add frames to the frameset using javascript?

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I searched and found a lot of 'solutions' for people having similar problems, but those don't seem to apply here.

The target page looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why do you even *need* to use frameset? It's deprecated technology... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: When I use the code for the iframe, clicking links on the main frame would cause the iframe to vanish. If you could tell me how to @include a certain frame instead of a URL to my UserScript, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: This is the origin of my problem http://i.imgur.com/Gsgqi2t.png. I'd like to add another frame at the bottom of the main frame.

Comment: Also, the main frame is constantly being updated, while the content of the new frame should be fixed(static?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to add a new `<frame>`. You must also adjust the `rows` or `cols` attribute of the containing `<frameset>`.

Also, if the frameset has an `id`, ***use*** it instead of trying to get the node by tagname. (Ids are fast and unique.)

Code like this will work (for now):

You can **[see the code in action at this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qifime/)**.

```
var parent      = document.getElementById ("mainset");
var child       = document.createElement ("frame");
child.style     = "background-color: pink;";

parent.appendChild (child);
parent.rows     = "30%,30%,30%"

var docRdyInt   = null;
var frmCW       = child.contentWindow;
if (frmCW) {
    //-- Must wait for the new frame to be writable, esp in Firefox.
    docRdyInt   = setInterval (createFramedPage, 50);
}
else {
    alert ("Oopsie! may be a rendering delay in some cases. Try code from console.");
}

function createFramedPage () {
    if (frmCW.document.readyState == "complete") {
        clearInterval (docRdyInt);
        frmCW.document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Hello World!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That (kinda) worked.
As you can see here http://imgur.com/LsBvDgq, the frame has been succesfully created. However, I do get the rendering delay alert and I'm not at all familiar with stuff like that. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure the script only runs on the top frame.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4190594/331508).  After that, if you still get the alert but the frame is added, just comment out the alert.

Comment: Error running script: frame stuffs
TypeError: Cannot convert 'parent' to object
Error thrown at line 23, column 0 in <anonymous function>():
    parent.appendChild (child);

Comment: You're going to have to open a new question with the **exact details** needed to replicate that new problem. The code works, see [the linked jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ganitarabolu/), at least for most current browsers (not tested/coded on/for IE).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just installed firefox with greasemonkey and it works indeed. It just doesn't work with opera/violentmonkey.

Comment: Any other details you need?

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594334/adding-frames-to-an-existing-frameset-using-a-userscript-works-with-firefox-wh
I'm trying to give as many relevant details as possible, but I'm not sure what is relevant and what isn't.